# How can I customize contact form code to send a copy to another email?

Tags: php, wordpress, email

I installed a theme on my wordpress website and I would like to modify the code of the contact owner form.
Can somebody help with this code?
I would like to send a copy to my email everytime when somebody send an email to the supplier from this website/portal.
What and where can I add the code?

Here is the link of the [file](http://forevent.ro/wp-content/themes/directory2/ait-theme/ajax)

```html
<?php

/*
 * AIT WordPress Theme Framework
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2013, Affinity Information Technology, s.r.o. (http://ait-themes.com)
 */


class AitContactOwnerAjax extends AitFrontendAjax
{

 /**
  * @WpAjax
  */
 public function send()
 {
  $matches = array();
  preg_match_all('/{([^}]*)}/', $_POST['response-email-content'], $matches);

  foreach($matches[1] as $i => $match){
   $_POST['response-email-content'] = str_replace($matches[0][$i], $_POST[$match], $_POST['response-email-content']);
  }

  $_POST['response-email-content'] = str_ireplace(array("\r\n", "\n"), "<br />", $_POST['response-email-content']);

  $senderName = isset($_POST['response-email-sender-name']) ? $_POST['response-email-sender-name'] : '';

  $headers = array(
   'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8',
   'Reply-To: '.$_POST['user-name'].' <'.$_POST['user-email'].'>',
   'From: '.$senderName.' <'.$_POST['response-email-sender-address'].'>', 
  );
  //$headers = 'From: '.$_POST['user-name'].' <'.$_POST['user-email'].'>' . "\r\n";
  wp_mail($_POST['response-email-address'], $_POST['response-email-subject'], $_POST['response-email-content'], $headers, null);
  $this->sendJson(array('message' => sprintf(__("Mail sent to %s", 'ait'), $_POST['response-email-address'])));
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$headers = array(
        'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8',
        'Reply-To: '.$_POST['user-name'].' <'.$_POST['user-email'].'>',
        'From: '.$senderName.' <'.$_POST['response-email-sender-address'].'>', 
        'CC: '.$yourname.' <'.$youremail.'>', 
    );
```

Comment: So my code will look like                                                                         
        'CC: '.$forevent.' <'office@forevent.ro'>',

Comment: eg . `'CC: Ralph John Galindo < ralphjesy@gmail.com>'`

Comment: it doesn't work this code ... i attached the link of the file if can helps

Comment: Did you get some error ? It should be working. Try `Cc:` . [Read here] (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/)

Comment: I don't have any error but doesn't work. I tried to send text to one supplier from portal but even can't receive anything.

Comment: Hi. I did some changes and now it works very good. Thanks Ralph John for your help

Comment: sure . no problem :)